# CSS transition not smooth for one element on hover, but is smooth when mouse moved away

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've got the following CSS and HTML. The problem is, that when the mouse is moved over the button, the red rectangle flashes to the center instead of smoothly moving to the center. It is strange because when the mouse is moved away from the button, it moves back slowly. How can I make the red rectangle move to the center smooth?

```css
  .btn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px 45px;
    margin: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .btn .rect {
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .btn .top-left {
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
  }
  .btn .bottom-right {
    bottom: -10px;
    right: -10px;
  }
  .red-translucent {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .blue-translucent {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .btn-text {
    z-index: 99999;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  .btn:hover .rect {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

```html
  <div class='btn'>
    <span class='btn-text'>button</span>
    <div class='rect top-left blue-translucent'></div>
    <div class='rect bottom-right red-translucent'></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting top, right, bottom, left for .rect for the not :hover state?

Comment: @Sheraff just tried adding this code: `.btn .rect {
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .btn .top-left {
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    bottom: unset;
    right: unset;
  }
  .btn .bottom-right {
    top: unset;
    left: unset;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: -10px;
  }`, didn't work

Comment: The browser can't interpolate between `unset` and `10px` afaik. You need actual numbers.

Comment: @Sheraff found a fix, check answer if you're interested

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, it didn't work with `bottom: -10px` and `right: -10px`. I'm not sure if this has to do with my code or if this is a browser problem, but the easy fix is to use the `top` and `left` properties instead:

```css
  .btn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px 45px;
    margin: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .btn .rect {
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .btn .top-left {
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
  }
  .btn .bottom-right {
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .red-translucent {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .blue-translucent {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .btn-text {
    z-index: 99999;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  .btn:hover .rect {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

```html
  <div class='btn'>
    <span class='btn-text'>button</span>
    <div class='rect top-left blue-translucent'></div>
    <div class='rect bottom-right red-translucent'></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.red-translucent {
    background-color: red;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform` instead of `top, left, bottom, right` like this:

```
.btn {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    padding: 30px 45px;
    margin: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.btn .rect {
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
    position: absolute;
}
.btn .top-left {
    transform: translate(-10px, -10px);
}
.btn .bottom-right {
    transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}
.red-translucent {
    background-color: red;
}
.blue-translucent {
    background-color: blue;
}
.btn-text {
    z-index: 99999;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.btn:hover .rect {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

This will work smoothly on either the `move-in` or `move-out` of the pointer.